# psql cannot start on Mac M1 + Monterey

Tags: postgresql, homebrew, apple-m1, macos-monterey

On my new Mac M1 (Monterey), I tried to install Postgres with brew:

```
brew install postgresql@14
```

After installation is completed, I can see that the service is running:

```
brew services list
> postgresql@14 started johndoe ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql@14.plist
```

Problem is when I try to issue the psql command I get the following:

```
psql: error: connection to server on socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: FATAL:  role "johndoe" does not exist
```

I tried to uninstall postgres and reinstall it with brew but the same thing occurs. Can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create the database user `johndoe` by

```
createuser -Upostgres -d johndoe
```

first. The `-d` flag allows the new user to create new databases. This can be done by

```
createdb -Ujohndoe mydb
```

After that you can connect to the new database as user `johndoe` by

```
psql -Ujohndoe -dmydb
```

Comment: the createuser command causes the following error: 'createuser: error: connection to server on socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: FATAL:  role "postgres" does not exist'. It's like the postgres user does not exist

Comment: After uninstall and reinstall again, I did "initdb --locale=C -E UTF-8 /opt/homebrew/var/postgres". Now the psql postgres command works and I can create new role.